# The API with ID xxx doesn’t include a route with path /* having an integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have HTTP API Gateway + Lambda setup. When I try to trigger the API I get 500 HTTP error:

> The IAM role configured on the integration or API Gateway doesn't have permissions to call the integration.

The API Gateway is listed in the Lambda's triggers, but there's an error message there too:

> The API with ID xxx doesn’t include a route with path /* having an integration arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::function:lambda-name.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was that I *published* my Lambda and had multiple [versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html) of it, but I added the resource-based policy only to the unversioned function and not to the versioned ones. After I added a policy to the version of the Lambda function that was used by the API Gateway, the error disappeared.

For those who use Terraform resource `aws_lambda_permission` - you have to specify the `qualifier` argument, use the Lambda version as the value for it.

My resource-based policy:

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue but without using function version. I have one function per API stage and I had to change the source arn as follow:
"${data.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.neorezo-cms-content.execution_arn}/*"

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this problem (bug?) by putting the permissions on the IAM role with which API Gateway invokes the Lambda function.

From the [AWS docs for API Gateway V2 command line](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigatewayv2/update-authorizer.html):

```
--authorizer-credentials-arn (string)

    Specifies the required credentials as an IAM role for API Gateway to invoke the authorizer. To specify an IAM role for API Gateway to assume, use the role's Amazon Resource Name (ARN). To use resource-based permissions on the Lambda function, don't specify this parameter.
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was removing the extra /* at the end of the arn. & then it worked.