# The API with ID xxx doesn’t include a route with path /*

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I have an "issue" with the following AWS setup:

```
// -----------
// API Gateway
// -----------

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "http_api_gateway" {
  name          = var.api_gateway_name
  protocol_type = "HTTP"

  tags = {
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "http_api_dev_stage" {
  api_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_api.http_api_gateway.id
  name        = "dev"
  auto_deploy = true

  tags = {
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer" "http_api_gateway_authorizer_test" {
  name                              = var.api_gateway_test_authorizer_name
  api_id                            = aws_apigatewayv2_api.http_api_gateway.id
  authorizer_type                   = "REQUEST"
  authorizer_uri                    = aws_lambda_function.auhtorizing_lambda.invoke_arn
  authorizer_payload_format_version = "2.0"
  enable_simple_responses           = "true"
  authorizer_result_ttl_in_seconds  = 0
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "test_custom_route" {
  api_id             = aws_apigatewayv2_api.http_api_gateway.id
  authorization_type = "CUSTOM"
  authorizer_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.http_api_gateway_authorizer_test.id
  route_key          = "POST /test-custom"
  target             = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.http_api_gateway_sqs_integration_test.id}"
}

// ------
// Lambda
// ------

resource "aws_lambda_function" "auhtorizing_lambda" {
  filename = var.auth_lambda_zip_file_path
  role     = aws_iam_role.auhtorizing_lambda_default_role.arn

  architectures = ["x86_64"]
  function_name = var.auth_lambda_name
  handler       = "main"
  memory_size   = "512"
  package_type  = "Zip"
  runtime       = "go1.x"
  skip_destroy  = "false"
  timeout       = "15"
  layers        = [data.aws_lambda_layer_version.layer_version.arn]

  tags = {
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow-invokation-from-api-gateway" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = var.auth-lambda-name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.http-api-gateway.execution_arn}/*/*"
}
```

And when I go to the lambda's configuration I see this error:

[image]

I said "issue", because it seems everything is working fine, but the error is being shown and I cannot understand the reason, and if there is some actual issue or it is a console bug.
I have tried to change the TF configuration to be with single `/*` but the same error occurs.

Has anyone faced similar issue or knows if I'm missing something here and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Try adding `/*/*/*`.

Comment: @MarkoE just tried it, but I'm getting the same error

Comment: Interesting, that was supposed to be working based on the AWS docs. Can you try with the following: `"arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:<aws account id>:${aws_apigatewayv2_api.http-api-gateway.id}/*/*/*"`, where you would need to add the AWS account id?

Comment: @MarkoE I tried it and replaced my source_arn with `source_arn = "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:<my account id>:${aws_apigatewayv2_api.http_api_gateway.id}/*/*/*"`, but still getting the same error, the only difference is that now the error sub-title contains three `/*` i.e. `arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:<my account id>:xxxx3x3yk/*/*/*`

Comment: Can you add the API Gateway code to the question as well?

Comment: @MarkoE I have added it to the question's config (at the top)

Comment: Can you try appending this to the execution ARN: `/dev/POST/*`? As a side note, I think `enable_simple_responses           = "true"` should be a boolean, not string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254904/discussion-between-krispetkov-and-marko-e).

Comment: @MarkoE I moved the discussion to the chat ☝️ as it becomes too long

Comment: @adarsha-jha tagging you here, as you also had the same issue and was looking for an answer in the [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76009085/the-api-with-id-xxx-doesn-t-include-a-route-with-path-having-an-integration)